# Install module from github

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder

I'm new to Python and I have trouble installing the following module : https://github.com/noio/peas

I tried `!pip install peas` and `!pip install -e \ git+https://github.com/noio/peas`, which I found online, but none worked. I get the following errors, respectively :

> Collecting peas
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement peas (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for peas

and

> Directory '\' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.

NB : `!pip install packagename` worked for other packages. But I think I understand why it doesn't work here.

I am using Spyder 2.3.8 (and I don't know if it's relevant : Python 3.5.1 64bits, from Anaconda, on Windows 8).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First problem, that project uses Python 2.7, so you'll have to switch to that.

Secondly, the project doesn't have an installer (`setup.py`), my best suggestion for using it would be to just to download or clone the repo, and copy the `peas` folder (the module for the project) to the directory of whatever project you're working on. Then you should just be able to `import peas.networks` etc.